# Wordpress Delete attachment function

Tags: image, wordpress, attachment

someone can tell me which file/event/function is called by click on 'Delete permanently' link?

[image]
I must delete a attachment.

The real problem is that when I click on 'Delete Permanently' from the 'add Media' Dialog, the images is not deleted, but if I click first on 'Edit Image', and in this new tab I click on 'Delete Permanently', the image is effectively deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_delete_attachment( $attachmentid, $force_delete );
```

you can refers at [wp_delete_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the action hook called, you may be interested in [`delete_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_attachment) hook